# How to force websphere v7.0 to generate inlineschema?

Tags: web-services, wsdl, websphere

I am using RAD 8 and websphere 7 for developing web applications. I am working on a web service and I found that by default websphere generates XSD for input and output complex types and adds import element in WSDL. I wanted to know what configuration changes we need to make in websphere to generate schema inline with WSDL